# "last" style not working. Margin

Tags: css, image, margin

HTML

```
<div class="col-3"><a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="images/image1.jpg" title="New Home Number Two"><img src="images/thumb_image1.jpg" class="fade" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
<div class="col-3"><a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="images/image2.jpg" title="New Home Number Two"><img src="images/thumb_image2.jpg" class="fade" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
<div class="last"><a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="images/image3.jpg" title="New Home Number Three"><img src="images/thumb_image3.jpg" class="fade" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
```

CSS

```
        .col-3 {
    width:31.5%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1.8%;
    margin-bottom:1.6949%;
    display:block;
}

.last {
    width:31.5%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:1.6949%;
    display:block;
}
```

With this code. My images on the right should have 0 margin. But they dont. They have the same as col-3

Comment: from me its looks fine

Comment: must be something else in my code. or media queries thats effecting it. hmmm

Comment: yupp looks like its because of other css since .. code in your question is working fine

Comment: for divs you need not addply display: block as divs are by default block elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be same, because (31.5*3) + (1.8*2) = 98.1. So 1.9% is left at the right side as you have applied `float: left`. The blank space left at the right might look like margin.

Comment: Yeah your right. First time working with responsive im forgetting my calculator! I just simplifyed my calculations. Did a width:32% and a margin:2% witch equals a perfect 100%

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your width for classes .col-3 and .last should be 32% and margin-right for class .col-3 should be 2%.